# T-SQL Where Statement to depend on DECLARED Variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For EXAMPLE i have this query from C#:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[users]" +
               "WHERE " + ((class == "ADMIN") ? "class_id = 0;" : "class_id <> 0;")
```

My TASK was suppose to make this code as a stored proc so i used this code:

```
DECLARE @class VARCHAR(25);
IF @class = "ADMIN"
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[users]
    WHERE class_id = 0;
END

ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[users]
    WHERE class_id != 0;
END
```

How can i shorten my T-SQL code without typing the `SELECT * FROM [dbo].[users]`
all over again?.....

PS. I've used the DYNAMIC SQL Coding style but my team wouldn`t approve it..

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (@class = 'ADMIN' AND class_id = 0) OR (@class<> 'ADMIN' AND class_id <> 0)`

Comment: I give style points to Felix's solution to shorten the code but I discourage this solution as you put the burden on the query processor to handle your two cases unnecessarily at runtime.   The original pattern eliminates runtime lookup work as the OR is often fully evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[users]
WHERE (@class = 'ADMIN' AND class_id = 0) OR (@class <> 'ADMIN' AND class_id <> 0)
```

2 notes:

Use `<>` instead of `!=` because first is standard `SQL`.

Always use parametrized queries because of `SQL` injections.

Comment: Plus read excellent article by  Erland Sommarskog [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do this:

```
SELECT Class_id, Class_Name FROM 
(
 select * 
 ,case when class_id = 0 then 'Admin' --Add as many conditions as needed
 --when class_id = 1 then 'Teacher'
 else '' end as [ClassType]
 from dbo.Users
)A WHERE ClassType = @a
```

You can add multiple conditions easily this way in the `CASE` statement. Illustrated one in the comments.